# Command line tools not accessible from Eclipse on OSX

Tags: eclipse, macos, cmake, homebrew

I am using Eclipse on a macOS machine. CMake is present on my machine at `/usr/local/bin/cmake` and has been installed using Homebrew. Eclipse is at the latest version (2018-09).

I have the following target in a Makefile, which has been set up and is visible from Eclipse:

```
all:
    ./configure
    Rscript -e "Rcpp::compileAttributes()"
    R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source .
```

Inside the `configure` file, there is this code:

```
cd src/build;cmake ..
```

However, when I double click the `all` target in Eclipse, I get the following message:

```
make all
./configure
./configure: line 1: cmake: command not found
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

I remember that some time ago this target worked out of the box on macOS. I can also launch CMake from a terminal without any trouble.

`echo $PATH` shows different behaviour:

- If called from a standard macOS terminal, it yields `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin`
- If called from a TM Terminal inside Eclipse, it yields `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

What is the most canonical way to have Eclipse detect my CMake installation ?

Comment: You may try to output content of `PATH` variable in Eclipse (e.g. with `echo $PATH`) and check whether it contains `/usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: I installed TM Terminal and you are correct, paths are different. I did not expect that... I edited my answer above.

Comment: I saw various solutions, which change from version to version of macOS, for the time being I will launch Eclipse from a terminal using /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse . I would happily change from a cleaner solution, for example editing a setting in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, the solution provided [here](https://superuser.com/questions/476752/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x-for-gui-applications) works. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/476752/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x-for-gui-applications/787415#787415) must be performed to see the changes immediately.