# Eclipse Console says cannot run cmake

Tags: c++, eclipse

I could not find the answer to my problem in the other similar questions.

After installing Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers on my mac, when I want to run a simple Hello program in C++, I get the following error in the console:

```
Error: build command 'cmake' not foundFailure running cmake:
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it Eclipse CDT? Eclipse does not usually come with a C++ compiler, so it is looking for CMake to find a compiler and build your project. It doesn't find one on your system.

Comment: Or to put it simpler - you cannot install Eclipse, write a *Hello World* program and then just compile it. Iirc there is some more setting up to do first.

Comment: It is Elcipse 2019.9. I chose the the Hello program in a list of ready sample codes the application shows on startup.

Comment: Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers. I edited the post. thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is part of the CDT package. In any case - you don't have a C++ compiler. See this for further info:

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html

Answer (score 3):

[That](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12499555/18920490) answer does the job perfectly:

- Under `Eclipse Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment` click the `select` button then check the `PATH` row and click `ok`.

[image: Figure 1]

- Double-click on the `PATH` row and modify the value by adding a `:`then the location of your make executable (for me `/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake` so I added `/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin)`

[image: Figure 2]

*Tested on macOS Monterey 12.6 and Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers 2022-09 (4.25.0)*

Answer (score 0):

I followed the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52440874/8682939) and it worked.

- Make sure to replace the `PATH string` by your `echo $PATH` output in the `Info.plist`, as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/541068). Also, execute the command suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/787415).

I am on *macOS Catalina 10.15* and *Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)*.

**Ps:** I also tried to set the environment variables on Eclipse, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12499555/8682939), but it did not work.